# Unity 2D - how to check if my gameobject/sprite is below ceratin Y lvl?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been trying to get a script working to check if my player is below a certain Y lvl, for a platformer. so it can be respawned to the beginning, But how do I put the y lvl inside a variable to check it? i cant figure it out lol

Comment: You can have two different approaches. First as mentioned in the answer you can check player's position and second option is just add a Collider at that position and when the player 'hit' that collider you will know that it reached the destination where you should respawn it.

Answer (score 3):

In the Update() run something like:

```
if(player.transform.position.y < 1)
 {
           //do something
 }
```

where 'player' is the GameObject in question.

Comment: The 'if' statement doesn't work, it doesn't recognize 'player' in the current context.
i tried something similar, by putting the position into a public variable. got the same error as here, until i created a variable *public Player player;* but then got the namespace error. the second public variable should make a box in the inspector that i can drag an object into right?

Comment: my original idea:


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class death : MonoBehaviour {

    public float playerY ;
    public Player player ;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        playerY = player.Transform.position.y;
    }
}

Comment: you should be able to just be running the code ive shown in the update function, there shouldnt be a need to assign the position to another variable constantly

Comment: @EasyEden When you get a "not recognised in current context" error it means that you are using a variable that has not been decleared yet. Just replace player with the name of the GameObject you are using. if this script is placed on the object you are checking the height of you can just remove the player part. This answer is fundamentally correct, it just can't be copied and pasted directly into your code.

Answer (score 2):

I am **assuming** you want to just want to *compare* (==, <=, >=, all that *jazz* is what I mean by comparing just in case you were not aware) the Y value to something like 10 for example. This is easy and you don't even need a variable **necessarily** for this.

```
//For the object position relative to the world
if(transform.position.y == 10) //"transform" gives you acces to the transform component 
{                              //of the object the script is attached to
    Debug.Log("MILK GANG");
}

//For the object position relative to its Parent Object
if(transform.localPosition.y == 10)
{
    Debug.Log("MILK GANG");
}
```

If you want to **change** the *value* of the ***position of your object*** then

```
transform.position = new Vector2(6, 9)//Nice
                                      //BTW new Vector2 can be used if you dont
                                      //want to assign a completely new variable
```

**However**, if you want to get a *reference* (Basically a variable that tells the code your talking about this component) to it.

```
private Transform Trans;

void Awake() //Awake is called/being executed before the first frame so its
{            //better than void Start in this case
    Trans = GetComponent<Transform>();

    Trans.position = new Vector2(69, 420); //Nice
}
```

This is the *code* way of doing it but there's another way that uses **Unity**

```
[SerializeField] private Transform Trans; 

//[SerializeField] makes the variable changeable in Unity even if it is private so you
//can just drag and drop on to this and you good to go
```

Hope this help
if it doesn't
then welp I tried lel

Comment: While you don't necessarily need a *public* field for the threshold value, you absolutely should have it as some form of field (usually a ```const```)!

Comment: @Immersive I don't think I quite understand what you mean
I didn't use public anywhere
either that or theres somthing i dont understand

Comment: don't hardcode important numbers as direct values, especially when those numbers are used in multiple places. At the very least, put them in a const.

Comment: @Immersive ah ok

Answer (score 2):

You can use a script added to gameobject to check `transform.position` of the object.

```
if(transform.position.y < ylvl)
{
//do something
}
```

where `ylvl` is the integer of the height you want to check